# Android: Cannot read text in EditBox inside a DialogBox

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to get user input using a pop-up dialog box. I am able to show the dialog box with an EditText, and the user can enter the input. But when I try to get this value, I just get a null.

It's a simple enough code. I'm probably missing something really elementary here. Not sure what!

```
private void getUserInput(String prompt) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(prompt);
    final EditText inputBox = new EditText(this);
    builder.setView(inputBox);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String str = "";
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "OK button clicked");
                    if (inputBox.getText() != null) { //PROBLEM: why is inputBox.getText null?? 
                        str = "null";
                    } else {
                        str = inputBox.getText().toString();
                    }
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "input text >>>" + str);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Have you actually set text in the EditText?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: The user enters text in the edit dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you've got

```
if (inputBox.getText() != null)
```

you're setting str to null, but checking inputBox.getText() is NOT null; shouldn't that `!=` be `== null`?  (Although, really, you should probably be checking `inputBox.getText().equals("")`.)

Comment: No, what he has is correct. He is checking to make sure that the string is \NOT\ null. `.equals` would be used for string comparisson.

Comment: Except that if `inputBox.getText() == null`, the current code will then attempt to call `inputBox.getText().toString()` which will be `null.toString()` and fall over.

Comment: Thankyou, Thankyou, Thankyou! Such a "Duh!" moment! I really should have got more sleep last night ;-) .